# Scanner.hasNext(String s) for "\\d\\s\\d" fails

Tags: java, regex, java.util.scanner

I can't figure out why this loop does not execute even once:

```
String s = "1 2\n3 4";
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(s);
while(scanner.hasNext("\\d\\s\\d")) {
    System.out.printf("%d %d\n", scanner.nextInt(), scanner.nextInt());
}
```

To my understanding, "\d\s\d" means digit followed by whitespace followed by another digit - exactly what the input is like, but the loop never executes even once.

My intention is to use Scanner with stdin where I want to assure that input has a sequence of two-digit pairs separated by whitespace, but the code example above is simplified, as I assume I'm doing something wrong with how I use the regex.

Can anyone offer an explanation? Thanks in advance.

Comment: What output do you expect?

Comment: I would expect two lines containing the two integers each, so line 1: "1 2", line 2: "3 4"

Answer (score 0):

The pattern `String` provided to [`hasNext(String)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#hasNext-java.lang.String-) is applied after the tokenization of the `Scanner`.

> Returns true if the **next token** matches the pattern constructed from
>   the specified string.

By default, that is whitespace. So `\\d\\s\\d` is applied to the character `1` in your `String s`. Obviously, that doesn't match.

Comment: I see. So to resolve this, I would expect I need to specify scanner.useDelimiter("\\n") right? That doesn't work either though... :(

Comment: @Caleb9 Don't limit yourself to `Scanner`. Consume the full line and check after the fact.

Comment: Thanks. I've edited the question to be more specific. I want to consume always two pairs of digits separated by a whitespace from stdin. Be that file with new-lines or without. Does that make sense?

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comments, I believe you are better off using `String#split` here:

```
String s = "1 2\n3 4";
toks = s.split( "\n" );
for (String tok: toks)
    System.out.printf("<%s>%n", tok);
```

**Output:**

```
<1 2>
<3 4>
```

**PS:** You can use `Scanner` also by using regex to match your numbers:

```
String s = "1 2\n3 4";
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(s);
while(scanner.hasNext("\\d+")) {
    System.out.printf("<%d %d>%n", scanner.nextInt(), scanner.nextInt());
```

**Output:**

```
<1 2>
<3 4>
```

Comment: Not quite, I want to use scanner to validate correct structure to the input. Your solution splits it by lines, I want to assure that there are two digits available on input for consuming them in the loop body. Thanks nevertheless.

Comment: I've also added a `Scanner` based solution.